# How to keep the Value of a Textfield with Javascript after adding new ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, textfield

I coded a bit with Javascript. I fill a div tag with some Checkboxes Textfields but always when I add a new Textfield it refreshes every textfield instead of just adding a new one.

```
document.getElementById('addfeld').innerHTML+="<input type='checkbox' name=' "+checkname+"' id='"+checkid+"'><input type='textfield' name ='"+txtname+"' id='"+txtid+"'/><br>";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wyqd6/1/

How can I keep the Value of the previous textfields?

EDIT NOTE: Fixed the jsfiddle link without code mistake

Comment: Bypassing the "Please post code in your question" warning when adding a JSFiddle link doesn't mean you should paste your JSFiddle link within a code block. The majority of people who come to this question will not bother to visit that link.

Comment: Thank you, I will not do the same mistake again.

Comment: You're overwriting the whole block instead of just appending to the existing block. Also why += all those different variables when ++ on one `id` would suffice? zavg has the right answer. Here's some ideas free of charge ;) http://jsfiddle.net/Wyqd6/4/

Comment: @Shanimal I need these variables for some SQL Querys. That's the reason I created them. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using **JQuery**, use

```
$('#addfeld').append()
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('addfeld').innerHTML +=
```

Here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dr6Le/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append` instead of adding to innerHTML. Like this:

```
$('#addfeld').append("<input type='checkbox' name=' "+checkname+"' id='"+checkid+"'><input type='textfield' name ='"+txtname+"' id='"+txtid+"'/><br>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wyqd6/3/

EDIT: Added code.

Comment: You should post the relevant code within the answer, otherwise this is essentially a *link only answer*.